# Yoroi mobile app isn't showing Add wallet (Shelley era)

Tags: wallet, yoroi, shelley

I have a question regarding Yoroi mobile. My friend has been using Yoroi Mobile from official source since May 2021. Today, she opened her wallet and did not see "Shelley Era" next to the word "Add wallet" (see attached image).

She double-checked the updated version and made sure she has been using the latest one. After she restored the old wallet on that Yoroi Mobile by entering 24 recovery phrases, it didn't show the wallet name.

So is there anything abnormal?

Does anyone know what's going on with Yoroi Mobile?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the new update from Emurgo has slightly changed Yoroi app's UI. However, regarding wallet recovery, I wanna say the following: the wallet's name is always stored in the wallet itself and not recovered when you enter a mnemonic phrase. So in this sense, everything is OK. In Yoroi, you can give a new (or the same) name to your old wallet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help